# Functions that are used for token transfers for ERC20 and ERC721 tokens

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, events, erc-721, logs

Let's suppose there is a contract address A of an erc721 token B. If I want to **monitor all of its transfers** from A to another address say C then should I only filter the Transfer function or should I also monitor safeTransferFrom and transferFrom [here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721). If yes then is there any other event apart from these three that I should be monitoring? And if no then why?

If the same scenario is considered for an erc20 contract then which functions should be monitored just Transfer or transferFrom as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ERC20, all these functions emit the exact same event:

```
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
```

On ERC721, all these functions emit the exact same event:

```
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId);
```

Comment: So you mean just monitoring the transfer event is enough?

Comment: @mahamzaidi: Yes. You wrote things like "which events should be monitored just Transfer or transferFrom as well?", while there is no such event `transferFrom`. It's a function.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the description.

Comment: @mahamzaidi: There is no function `Transfer`. There is function `transfer` and event `Transfer`. And in either case, you don't "monitor functions", you monitor events.